# How to run "pushd"  using backticks?

Tags: ruby

How do you run `pushd` and `popd` using backticks?

Whenever I run `pushd /tmp` in backticks I get an error:

```
"No such file or directory - pushd /tmp"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ruby shell-outs (backticks) each run in a new subshell, so it doesn't work perhaps in the way that you are thinking:

```
a = `pwd`
`cd '/tmp'`
b = `pwd`
b == a         # => true
b == "/tmp"    # => false
```

Also, are you sure `pushd` works in your shell? Maybe look at using ruby's `system` or `popen3` if you want something more useful than the backtick syntax.

`Dir#chdir` accepts a block. Here's an example from [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-chdir) if all you need is to run some commands in a directory then change back:

```
Dir.chdir("/var/spool/mail")
puts Dir.pwd
Dir.chdir("/tmp") do
  puts Dir.pwd
  Dir.chdir("/usr") do
    puts Dir.pwd
  end
  puts Dir.pwd
end
puts Dir.pwd
```

Comment: I've worked around the problem by storing Dir.pwd into a string, running Dir.chdir then popping back to the old directory with another call to Dir.chdir. Not as elegant as pushd/popd IMO. There is also a Shell class which does have pushd and popd but I cannot find much documentation about how to use that.

Comment: `Dir.chdir` accepts a block - it executes the block then returns to the previous directory - [see the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-chdir)

Comment: Updated my answer with this link

Comment: I really like passing it into a block. Nice one. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can't use *pushd* with backticks that way; *pushd* is a Bash builtin, not an executable. However, you can get similar functionality with the Ruby [Shell](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/shell/rdoc/Shell.html) module.

```
require 'shell'
shell = Shell.new
shell.pushd '/tmp'
shell.popd
```